# How to Move Terrain to Another Unity Project File?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, terrain, unity3d-terrain

How can I import terrains onto another Unity project? I am new to developing on Unity.

I would like to place this terrain...
[image]

Onto this project. And as you can see...
[image]

Nothing shows!

So, how do I make the entire terrain appear on this Unity project file?

**Since I am new to Unity, detailed explanations are greatly appreciated.** Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

I added terrain data and now it looks like this

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import Terrain Data and replace missing textures within Terrain Layers.